# Cannot find method setValues(string)? Attempting to make a timestamp based on current time, if checkbox has been marked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm still trying to create a time trigger, that examines whether a checkbox has been edited that day to 'true' and to make a timestamp in the next column to show when it was last edited. This is the code I have below, I haven't even gotten to getting it to run yet. Shows:
Cannot find method setValues(string). Line 12.

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var timestampFormat = "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss";
  var now = new Date();
  var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("C2:C200");
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_LMkYec4CymMQZ6vdCswkr2UGiGPIOGLlLBMlLYEw3k");
  var checkRange = sheet.getRange("C:C");
  var checkBox = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  if (checkBox.getValue() == true) {
    checkRange.setValues(Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, timestampFormat));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use onEdit():

I hope that you realize that you can't run this function without an event object.
It may have to be an installable trigger is other people are using the spreadsheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='WhatEverSheetNameYouPutHere') return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1)=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss");
  }
}
```

Comment: So when I try and run this, it just sets all the time stamps in column C to the current time stamp, instead of just the rows in C where the corresponding row in B is set to a ticked checkbox. Not sure why.